# Array into mysql database field

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, forms, post

I have an array of form values that get posted across from one page to another.

```
$_POST['ingredients'];
```

The items in the array were posted in the form of `ingredients[]`.

How could i concatenate all the values and put them into one field of a row in a database

An example of a mysql code would be perfect.

Thanks

```
$ingredient_method = $_POST['conValue'];
$ingredient_type = $_POST['OneWordDescription'];
$ingredient_element = $_POST['ingredients'];


$sql="INSERT INTO tbl_Recipe (recipe_id, ingredient_method, ingredient_type, ingredient_element)
VALUES
('',$_POST[conValue]','$_POST[OneWordDescription]','$_POST[ingredients]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";
```

Comment: This is currently to vague to answer.. They way you describe it you want to just concatenate all the values and put them into one field of a row in a database.

Comment: how would i do this? Thanks @KellyCopley

Comment: Being that you are seeking code, it all depends.. Like I said, this is vague.. Which way are you interacting with MySQL? do you really just want a string that says "Salt Sugar Water"?

Comment: yes for the time being, I can code them into a separate table at a later date. I am performing a full text search on it you see.

Answer (score 4):

You have a few options:

1. Use PHP's [serialize](https://www.php.net/serialize) function to convert the array into a string before putting it into the database, and then [unserialize](https://www.php.net/unserialize) when you pull the data out.
2. Use PHP's [implode](https://www.php.net/implode) to turn the data into a string and then [explode](https://www.php.net/explode) when you pull the data out.
3. Create another table in MySQL, insert each value into the database as a separate row, and then use something like `INNER JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN` in your query pull the data out.

**Update**:

Now that you've posted code, I have to recommend you do NOT use `mysql_*` functions.  They are deprecated.  Use either [mysqli](https://www.php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo).  Also, **ALWAYS** use either [mysqli_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string) or [PDO::quote](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php) on values you receive from the user to prevent SQL injection attacks.

Here is an example using `serialize` and PDO:

```
//get the array
$ingredient_method = $_POST['conValue'];
$ingredient_type = $_POST['OneWordDescription'];
$ingredient_elements = $_POST['ingredients'];
if(!is_array($ingredient_elements)) {
    //do some error handling
}

//connect to the database
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$pass = 'dbpass';
try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

//serialize the string
$elements_str= serialize($ingredient_elements);

//prepare sql
$sql = 'INSERT INTO tbl_Recipe '.
           '(recipe_id, ingredient_method, ingredient_type, ingredient_element) '.
       'VALUES ( '.
            '"",'. //recipe_id
            $pdo->quote($ingredient_method).','.
            $pdo->quote($ingredient_type ).','.
            $pdo->quote($elements_str).
       ')';
// insert into database
$con->query($sql);
```

Comment: Then brace yourself for sql injection attacks.. Please don't do this!

Comment: @KellyCopley: so long as he's using msyqli_real_escape_string or PDO::quote, there should not be any worry about sql injection... and that really has nothing to do with `serialize` and `unserialize`

Comment: he was asking how to store an array in a data base and asked for an example with MySQL code.. Doesn't sound to me like he has a firm grasp on the basics yet.. Lets not give him a loaded gun just assuming he knows how to use it.

Comment: @Kelly Copley How is this potentially more dangerous than storing any piece of text in a database? By the way, just saw the OP's edit and you are absolutely right about the basics...

Comment: Thanks for your responses guys, I have updated my post. I would like to concatenate the values into one field

Comment: It's not if you know what you are doing, but if he doesn't know how to properly prepare/escape is queries then it is.

Comment: @KellyCopley, just updated my answer to mention deprecation of `mysql_*`, sql injection attacks, and gave some sample code

Comment: just as another note.. since he is storing this in a text based field it's probably not best to use serialize since it's return is a binary string.

Answer (score 0):

ok, not sure how you got to ingredients being an array BUT if this is the case then here we go.

first you can join the array using implode but check to see if there is anything there to avoid throwing warnings.

```
//check if $_POST['ingredients'] is available if not then use empty string
$ingredient_element = isset($_POST['ingredients']) ? $_POST['ingredients'] : "";

join the array 
$ingredient_element = implode(" ", $ingredient_element);
```

now the least you can do is use mysql_real_escape_string to sanitize your string but I would recommend learning about mysqli or PDO since mysql_ functions are deprecated.

```
//sanitize
$ingredient_element = mysql_real_escape_string($ingredient_element);
```

then just use $ingredient_element in your insert sql

$sql="INSERT INTO tbl_Recipe (recipe_id, ingredient_method, ingredient_type, ingredient_element)
VALUES
('',$$ingredient_method','$ingredient_type','$ingredient_element')";

also if recipe_id is a integer id that is auto increment you can leave it blank but if you must use something there, you must use NULL in the place of ''

Comment: please do not use `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated

Comment: I think I mentioned this after stating that it was the least that could be done.